# Vimeo API - How to get "time available" field

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I need to programmatically get the time when my live video is scheduled. But calling

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/46055xxxx -u <my_token>
```

doesn't return the field, there are several other values as `created_time`, `modified_time`, `release_time`  but not the one I need.

Does anybody know if is it possible to get it via api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `-u` is the right curl option to use for authentication with the Vimeo API, use `-H` instead:

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#presenting-the-access-token

Second, the Live API is only available to Enterprise users, so depending on your account level you might not be able to get that scheduled event metadata anyway. You can try making a request to get the live event endpoint:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/live

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042881411-Live-API-access

Comment: the most importan information is that Vimeo API doesn't return those data if you haven't an enterprise account.